# how to rewrite composable that get data from API with async await

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, composable

I'm using composable to get data from API

**composable/category.ts**

```js
import { useHttp } from './Http'
import type { ICategory } from '@/models/category.model'

export const useCategory = () => {
  const categories = ref<ICategory[]>([])
  useHttp().get('/category').then((res) => categories.value = res.data)
  return { categories }
}
```

**someComponent.vue**

```
import { useCategory } from '@/composables/Category'
const { categories } = useCategory()
```

this codes work perfectly , the only **problem** is when I try to rewrite my code with **Async await** and **try catch** some error happens

```js
import { useHttp } from './Http'
import type { ICategory } from '@/models/category.model'

export const useCategory = async () => {
  const categories = ref<ICategory[]>([])
  async function get() {
    const res = await useHttp().get('/category')
    categories.value = res.data
  }
  onMounted(async () => {
    get()
  })
  return { categories }
}
```

[image]

> Property 'categories' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ categories:
> Ref<{ _id: string; title: string; }[]>; }>'.ts(2339)

How can I rewrite that composable with **async/await** and **try/catch** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error speaks for itself. Your function returns a `Promise<{ categories: Ref<...> }>`, not a `{ categories: Ref<...>}`. So you need to `await` it when using like so:

```js
const { categories } = await useCategory()
```

Or you can remove the `async` annotation in the function because there is no await inside it.

```js
export const useCategory = () => {
  const categories = ref<ICategory[]>([])
  async function get() {
    try {
        const res = await useHttp().get('/category')
        categories.value = res.data
    }
    catch(err){
        // Do something with the err
    }
  }
  onMounted(() => {
    get()
  })
  return { categories }
}
```